# CSS flex: Contain content within flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I noticed when using `flex` that the container's content is allowed to overflow the container (column). How can I prevent this? I would like the content to have the max height and max width of whatever the column size is.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-6 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:250px;">

  <div class="col-6" style="background:red;">

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-6 -->

  <div class="col-6" style="background:blue;">

    <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/e83cb50c2ff1043ed1584d05fb0938c9bd22ffd41db9154792f2c47fa6/discus-fish-1943755_1280.jpg" />

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: `style="max-height:100%"` on `img`

Comment: @mrogers But I would like to apply the style not to only the image but to anything that may ever appear in any `col`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a flex specific problem. you are limiting size of your image that is why it is overflowing.

Add this to your css

```
.col-6 img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

Here's a working snippet

```css
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[class*='col-'] {
 flex: 1;
}
.col-6 {
 -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%; 
    height:100%;
}
.col-6 img{
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:250px;">
  <div class="col-6" style="background:red;">  
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->   
 <div class="col-6" style="background:blue;">         
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/e83cb50c2ff1043ed1584d05fb0938c9bd22ffd41db9154792f2c47fa6/discus-fish-1943755_1280.jpg" />
 </div> <!-- /.col-6 -->
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Is there any way to apply this not just to an `img` but to anything that may ever appear in a `col`?

Comment: you can do it with javascript but not with css.

Comment: with javascript you can select all the child of the div with `child()` and add the same css for them. `display:block;max-width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest `overflow:scroll` because it's not clear how you want to deal with too much text. An image could be constrained and scaled down but if you do the same with copy it will become unreadable.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-6 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:250px;">

  <div class="col-6" style="background:red;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam egestas rutrum turpis, at iaculis risus laoreet vel. Integer at dui justo. Ut viverra vitae lacus sit amet sollicitudin. Curabitur molestie sollicitudin est, eget suscipit turpis interdum sit amet. Cras at viverra ligula. Sed sed finibus nisi. Sed dictum sem a dui sollicitudin, eget volutpat neque vestibulum. In imperdiet urna a urna venenatis, id tristique erat interdum. Aenean dapibus molestie lorem, ut egestas massa pretium nec.

Nullam vitae accumsan tortor. Nulla sit amet diam a nibh porta eleifend a sed ligula. Donec sagittis vulputate ante molestie auctor. Donec tincidunt, nisl et vulputate venenatis, felis lorem imperdiet mauris, quis pellentesque dolor leo non enim. In in commodo nibh. Aliquam sed ullamcorper augue. Etiam nec turpis libero. Aliquam cursus venenatis tortor eget ornare. Quisque in volutpat urna, quis aliquam est. Fusce hendrerit ligula eget vehicula rutrum. Praesent id odio urna.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-6 -->

  <div class="col-6" style="background:blue;">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1920-1920-8.jpg" />

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-6 -->

</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```